# How to setup a build in Gradle to not deploy JUnit test cases to JBoss AS 7.1

Tags: java, junit, jboss, gradle, build.gradle

I have a very very simple JSF2 application that simply shows a hello world page. The matter is that this application has a JUnit test case. When a build the war file to deploy it in JBoss AS 7.1, the test class goes with it, causing some problems to load the application.

The `build.gradle` file is below

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

// Needed in order to make the test running to work
sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.classesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
sourceSets.test.output.resourcesDir = sourceSets.test.output.classesDir

def hibernateVersion = "4.3.7.Final"
def weldVersion = "1.1.27.Final"
def unidadesVersion = "1.0.0"
def demoiselleVersion = "2.4.1"
def arquillianVersion = "1.1.5.Final"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    runtime 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    runtime 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0-SP1'
    runtime 'org.jboss:jandex:1.2.2.Final'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:'+arquillianVersion    
    testCompile 'br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component:demoiselle-junit:2.3.1'
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {
            facet name: "java", version: "1.7"          // Java version
            facet name: "jst.web", version: "3.0"       // Dynamic Web Application
            facet name: "jst.jsf", version: "2.2"       // Java Server Faces
            facet name: "wst.jsdt.web", version: "1.0"  // JavaScript
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

In my tests I perform some dependency injection, that's why I have **Weld** and **Jandex** included in the test dependencies.

I expected that, because the test cases are localed in src/test/java, they would not be included in war file, but it seems I´m wrong about that!

What am i missing? How to exclude those files from the war?

### Update 1

After acting like [Peter Niederwieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser) suggested, the `build.gradle` file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

def hibernateVersion = "4.3.7.Final"
def weldVersion = "1.1.27.Final"//"2.2.7.Final" Demoiselle 2.4.1 não é compatível com Weld 2
def unidadesVersion = "1.0.0"
def demoiselleVersion = "2.4.1"
def arquillianVersion = "1.1.5.Final"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jboss.weld.se:weld-se-core:'+weldVersion

    runtime 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    runtime 'javax.enterprise:cdi-api:1.0-SP1'
    runtime 'org.jboss:jandex:1.2.2.Final'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

war {
}

eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {
            facet name: "java", version: "1.7"          // Java version
            facet name: "jst.web", version: "3.0"       // Dynamic Web Application
            facet name: "jst.jsf", version: "2.2"       // Java Server Faces
            facet name: "wst.jsdt.web", version: "1.0"  // JavaScript
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

This is what my Eclipse project looks like

[image]

And this is what the JBoss AS 7.1 deployment folder contains

[image]

The image aboce shows that the folders under `/src/test/java` were included in the war and deployed in JBoss.

### Update 2

I looked inside the generated war file in `build\lib`. It doesn't contain any of the test classes, so I believe that the JBoss panel performs a complete build and includes everything it can compile in another war and then deploies it.

So, I believe that the war plugin is working properly, not deploying any of the test files.

Mistery continues!

### Update 3

After some extra study I could finally understand what is going on. After running any Gradle task, like `Gradle clean` for instance, Gradle adds an entry to Eclipse's **Deployment Assembly**. This entry is precisely the test classes folder. Whith such an entry, the JBoss publishing agent will always deploy anything below `src/test/java`.

So, one way of fixing the problem is opening the project Properties window and manually removing that entry from there. However, Gradle is about automating the build and configurarion, so I would like be able to configure my Gradle build to not add such an entry there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This line effectively turns test classes into production classes: `sourceSets.test.output.classesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir`. Remove this line, it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried that and at this time the build.gradle do not contains those lines, but the problem remains.

Comment: That's very unlikely (if the test class really is in `src/test/java`). Make sure to save the build file, do a clean build, and double-check the results.

Comment: I did what you suggested and had the same result. Then, since this is a very small project, I decided to remove it from JBoss and delete its deployment folder, deleted all the sources and wiped out the project completely from the Eclipse Workspace. There was nothing left of it. Then I started again, adding piece by piece and checking the result. When I finally added the contents of src/test/java and built the war for the first time. After the deploy in JBoss, all the contents of the test folder where there. So, we are back to the starting point.